# Saving a bitmap into a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, bitmap, memorystream

Should I allocate the memory or just the object of the memory stream:
Is this OK?

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

If I need to define the MemoryStream size, how can I get it from Bitmap?

Comment: This should be just fine; are you experiencing specific problems?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

.NET is a managed environment: specifically, memory allocation is usually managed on your behalf by the .NET runtime. You don't typically need to allocate the memory yourself.

Sometimes, however, you do need to inform the runtime when you've finished with memory by using `Close()` or `Dispose()`. The `using` statement can be used to wrap a resource such as `MemoryStream` to tell the runtime that the memory can be reclaimed.

Comment: Thanks,
Now I think its clear.
I planed to save the stream in my class during the work, but seems like I should save it only during the process and not to keep it all time my app is live.

I thought it is better to save the picture as memorystream instead of Bitmap.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to preallocate memory.

You can get the size afterwards with `memoryStream.Length`.

---

After you've done what you need to with your `memoryStream`, be sure to dispose it (or wrap it all in a `using` statement).

Comment: Thanks,
Now I think its clear.
I planed to save the stream in my class during the work, but seems like I should save it only during the process and not to keep it all time my app is live.

I thought it is better to save the picture as memorystream instead of Bitmap.