# C# Converting 'bitmap' to 'jpeg' without saving to the file system?

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg

A special that camera I am using returns me only images in bitmap format. 
However, for the processes that I apply to that image (image processing), fails every time because of the image format.
And if the image is in ".jpeg" format everything works perfect.

My question is:

- Is there any way to convert a bitmap to jpeg **without saving to the 
  file system.**

I saw there were few answers telling conversion by saving the image to the file system. That's not what I want. I need to convert and return those images.

I saw that C# had a class (below) but could not deploy it because I didn't know how to :

```
System.Drawing.ImageFormatConverter
```

Thanks in advance for your time, and valuable helps.

Comment: see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666330/saving-a-bitmap-into-a-memorystream

Comment: How does the code look like that receives the bitmap?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your interest! Darth Paper, after converting to jpeg, I have to store the images as 'System.Drawing.Image'. Unfortunately, I am not quite fluent in C#. Do you have any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [look at imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/howto/upload-and-resize).

FreeImage could also be an alternative, though Ive found it a bit buggy at times.